# What is the correct Chinese expression for "Only child"?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

I noticed lots of compound words using "只" for "only", but what is the correct way to say "only child" (a child with no brothers, nor sisters)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Chinese expression for 'only Child' can be '**独生子女**(only child)','**独子**(only son)','**独女**(only daughter)'，or some more ancient or literary words like '**独苗**(only child)','**单丁**(only son)',**单根独苗**(only child or only descendant).

Native Chinese speakers may have other expressions like,

> 他膝下**仅有一女**。（He has only one daughter.）
>
> 他是那老汉**唯一的儿子**。（He is the only son of that old man.）
>
> 他是**三代单传**。（He is the only one son for several generations in the family.）

I hope the above helps.

Answer (score 7):

There's an exact word for `only child`:`独生子(女)`, especially in China mainland.

See [【天朝热词英文说~125】](http://bbs.koolearn.com/t-3970727-1-1.html)

> 根据family planning
>   policy（计划生育政策），一般情况下每个家庭只允许生育一个孩子，也就是我们所说的only/single child（独生子女）。

According to the context, there're also other expressions. From [youdao](http://dict.youdao.com/search?le=eng&q=only%20child&keyfrom=dict.top):

> If you have an only child, was this by choice or chance?
>
> 如果你只有一个孩子，那是你特意为之还是意外？
>
> After counting down for nine years, I was finally an only child.
>
> 在倒数计时了九年后，我终于是家里唯一的孩子了。